# about restricting outer measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

If $\mu_0$ is an outer measure on an algebra, we can extend the premeasure to an outer measure $\mu^*$. By Caratheodory's theorem, the collection of $\mu^*$-measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra. Is an outer measure $\mu^*$ restricted to $\mu^*$-measurable sets a measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. That's also part of Caratheodory's extension theorem.